Не загружаются данные из .env-файла
Использую Pycharm, PostgreSQL, SQLAlchemy, psycopg2, pydantic-settings
ОС Windows.
Не получается загрузить данные из файла .env.
Файл создан, данные указал.
Файл .env находится NameProject/.env
Файл Config.py находится NameProject/src/config.py
Все библиотеки импортированы.
Смотрел в интернете разные варианты: Вариант 1: пробовал установить плагин EnvFile для PyCharm. Выдаёт ошибку.(https://i.sstatic.net/AbeiwB8J.png)
Вариант 2: Настроить PyCharm для использования переменных окружения. выдаёт ту же ошибку, что и в первом варианте.
Вариант 3: Установил библиотеку python-dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv 
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict

load_dotenv()  

class Settings(BaseSettings):
   DB_HOST: str
   DB_PORT: int
   DB_USER: str
   DB_PASS: str
   DB_NAME: str

   model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=".env")

   @property
   def DATABESE_URL_psycopg2(self):
      return f"postgresql+psycopg2://{self.DB_USER}:{self.DB_PASS}@{self.DB_HOST}:{self.DB_PORT}/{self.DB_NAME}"

settings = Settings()

По итогу код выдаёт ошибку (https://i.sstatic.net/JYBlYW2C.png)
Вариант 4: Настроить через через библиотеки os. выдаёт ту же ошибку, что и в варианте 1. (https://i.sstatic.net/FyIIkJYV.png)
Что делаю не так? Подскажите в каком направление искать информацию или как решить данную проблему.

Добавьте код и сообщения об ошибках в текстовом формате
